# How did I get a checkmate in this game?

Tags: rules, endgame, checkmate

[image]

This is a position from an endgame I played that I do not understand. How did I get a checkmate in this game? Is this a glitch? I ask this because I am pretty sure that Black's queen could take my White queen.

Comment: The graphics are awful -- please use FEN (which this site supports) rather than a screenshot. With bad graphics and bad programming, I would just delete that app and get something better such as e.g. shredder.

Answer (score 2):

The position shown is *not* checkmate. As you say, the queen can be captured. Even if that wasn't the case, there are two squares the king can escape to, and there's also a pawn that could move to block the check.